# How can I use lambda for container comparison operator ?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is how I would use inbuilt function or new class as a custom comparator

```
priority_queue< int, vector<int>, greater<int> > third (myints,myints+4);

  // using mycomparison:
  priority_queue< int, vector<int>, mycomparison > q1;
class mycomparison
{ 
public: 
  bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int&rhs) const
  {
     return (lhs<rhs);
  }
};
  typedef priority_queue<int,vector<int>,mycomparison> q2;
```

But I wonder if I can use lambda functions there ..

Comment: Lambdas are functors, whereas containers need a functor *type*. You might be able to do something with `decltype` though (but I wouldn't expect it to work in MSVC2010).

Comment: Yes, you could use a lambda, but the lambda would need to be as global as the most global declaration of its use as a type which defeats the purpose and is generally messier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First define the lambda:

```
auto compareFunc = [](int a, int b) { return a > b; };
```

Then use decltype:

```
typedef priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(compareFunc)> q2;
```

Now when you use `q2`, pass in the function:

```
q2 myQueue(compareFunc);
```

Basically, priority_queue takes the type of a function as it's 3rd template argument, while the constructor takes a pointer to that function itself.

Comment: Note that this requires the creation of a global variable that must have the same visibility as `q2`. So if you need `q2` to be in a header, then you also need this global variable to be in a header. Which is not the easiest thing in the world if you want to use `auto`.

Comment: @NicolBolas, what would you suggest?

Comment: @Yola: I would suggest using a struct for the comparison function rather than a lambda. There is no advantage to using a lambda here.

Comment: Why do we need decltype in order to pass the lambda into the template args?