# Priority Queue Comparison

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm trying to declare a priority queue in c++ using a custom comparison function...

So , I declare the queue as follows:

```
std::priority_queue<int,std::vector<int>, compare> pq;
```

and here's the compare function :

```
bool compare(int a, int b)
{
   return (a<b);
}
```

I'm pretty sure I did this before, without a class,in a similar way, but now, this code doesn't compile and I get several errors like this :

```
type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Sequence, class _Compare> class std::priority_queue'
```

Is there a way to create a compare function similar to this but without using a class?

Thanks

Comment: Try `&compare`. If this doesn't work you can also use `std::less<int>`. It might be the case that the template parameter should be the type of the functor, not a functor/function value.

Comment: Thanks but no, &compare doesn't work.... The reason why I'm asking this is because I want to sort structs, bases on one of their valuse, so std::less wouldn't really work....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The template parameter should be the **type** of the comparison function. The function is then either default-constructed or you pass a function in the constructor of `priority_queue`. So try either

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(&compare)> pq(&compare);
```

or don't use function pointers but instead a functor from the standard library which then can be default-constructed, eliminating the need of passing an instance in the constructor:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::less<int> > pq;
```

http://ideone.com/KDOkJf

If your comparison function can't be expressed using standard library functors (in case you use custom classes in the priority queue), I recommend writing a custom functor class, [or use a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307532/how-can-i-use-lambda-for-container-comparison-operator).

Comment: Well... It's so strange but the first one doesn't compile for me.. I copied the code from Ideone and it doesn't work...

Comment: Actually I'm not sure... I'm using codeblocks 12.11 and the compiler installed along with it...

Comment: But it has the disadvantage that if you change the signature of `compare`, you also have to change `CompareType` accordingly. The other code makes use of `decltype` which will get you the type of what's in `()`, but it's only available since C++11.

Comment: Yeah... this works, but as with Emil Condrea's answer I don't understand why......

Comment: Ahh ok ok got it .. You need to pass a type as another guy said to the pqueue... Thanks

Comment: The thing is: you need to tell the priority queue both the type and a pointer to your comparison function. The type goes into the template parameter list, but the type is not enough, so the constructor accepts a *value* of this type, and since the type is a function pointer type, you can then pass a function pointer. The ampersand `&` gives you a pointer to a function. I hope this explains it. ;)

Comment: Yeah thanks, so that was what the decltype function does.... It feeds the pqueue with the type and then the ampersand gives to the constructor the address of the actual compare function. Yes thanks a lot! I now understand it :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use C++11 [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) function. You need to create lambda object, pass it to the template using `decltype` and also pass it to the constructor. It looks like this:

```
auto comp = [] (int &a, int &b) -> bool { return a < b; };
std::priority_queue<int,std::vector<int>, decltype(comp) > pq (comp);
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the second parameter "std::vector<int>" in the template?

Comment: @MohammadMamunHossain: That's the default value for the underlying container.

Answer (score 7):

you have to specify function type and instantiate the function in `priority_queue` constructor.

```
#include <functional>

bool compare(int a, int b)
{
   return (a<b);
}

std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>,
                              std::function<bool(int, int)>> pq(compare);
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked perfectly for me.

```
struct compare{
    bool operator() (const int& p1,const int& p2 ){
         return p1<p2;
    }
};

int main(){
    priority_queue<int,vector<int>, compare > qu;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks the simplest among many solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a typedef. This compiles very well:

```
typedef bool (*comp)(int,int);
bool compare(int a, int b)
{
   return (a<b);
}
int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<int,std::vector<int>, comp> pq(compare);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't work because you didn't pass a function, only a type telling its signature.

Comment: Ahh thanks, this compiles perfectly, but I still don;t understand how this works, and the way I could add my custom comparison with it... It would be nice if you clarified a little bit! Thanks!

Comment: you are right, i forgot to add the function as parameter for constructor

Comment: i updated my answer , not forgeting this time to pass the compare function to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, bool (*)compare(int, int)> pq(compare);
```

Is another way not mentioned.