# std::priority_queue containing my own class

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Let me introduce my class:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <queue>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename HType>
class Huffman {

    class TreeOfLetters {
        HType Value;
        char Letter;
        TreeOfLetters *Root = nullptr;
        TreeOfLetters *Left = nullptr;
        TreeOfLetters *Right = nullptr;

        TreeOfLetters(HType _Value, char _Letter) : Value(_Value), Letter(_Letter) {
        };


    };

     auto compare = [](const TreeOfLetters &a,const TreeOfLetters &b){
    return a.Value < b.Value;};

    std::priority_queue(TreeOfLetters, std::set<TreeOfLetters>, compare);

public:
    Huffman(std::initializer_list<HType> _Values, std::initializer_list<char> _Chars);
    Huffman(const Huffman& orig) = delete;


};
```

What I want to achieve is to store pointers to Trees in the std::priority_queue in such a way that on top will be the one which the value is the highest.

I know that I could get a container whatever I like and then sort it but I want to use the std::priority_queue which will do it **automatically**.

Since I am not very familiar with c++11 features I am receiving some errors and I would highly appreciate your help with getting rid of them.

First of all I am not sure if my lambda is correct that is why I want some experts to cofirm whether my approuch is correct or not.

**WARNINGS WHICH I RECEIVE:**

> Unable to resolve identifier TreeOfLetters.
>
> Unable to resolve identifier compare.
>
> Unable to resolve identifier Value.

EDIT: Big thanks to Piotr and Thoran for their help I did overload the < operator so I add these lines to my class

```
bool operator<(const TreeOfLetters &a,const TreeOfLetters &b)
 {
   return a.Value < b.Value;
 }
```

I am still receiving an error from a following line I will highly appreciate an approuch what will help me to solve it.

```
 std::priority_queue <TreeOfLetters, std::vector<TreeOfLetters>, Compare> queue;
```

> In file included from Huffman.cpp:1:0:
>   Huffman.h:37:77: error: invalid declarator before ‘queue’

Comment: Your definition of the queue does not look right? Are you trying to use templates `set::priority_queue<TreeOfLetters,...>? Also the lamba is strange, make a struct overloading the () operator as the compare input.

Comment: yes I do so my definition of the queue should look like std::priority_queue<TreeOfLetters>(TreeOfLetters,std:set<TreeOfLetters,compare> ? I do not understand the third sentence in your comment could u show me the way?

Comment: You can't use `std::set` as a container for `std::priority_queue`. To use lambda, you could use `std::priority_queue<TreeOfLetters, std::deque<TreeOfLetters>, std::function<bool(const TreeOfLetters&,const TreeOfLetters&)>> pq{[](const TreeOfLetters &a,const TreeOfLetters &b){return a.Value < b.Value;}};`

Comment: You dont need to overload the operator for TreeOfLetters, but for the HType you are using. How are you using the Huffman class? What is HType in your usage?

Comment: Sometimes my HType is a float sometimes it is an int.

Comment: Ok, then you dont need to implement the < operator for HType. See also the example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of the Compare function and the queue looks strange. Did you mean something like this? This works for me in Visual C++

```
template <typename HType>
class Huffman {

    class TreeOfLetters {
        HType Value;
        char Letter;
        TreeOfLetters *Root;
        TreeOfLetters *Left;
        TreeOfLetters *Right;

        TreeOfLetters(HType _Value, char _Letter) : Value(_Value), Letter(_Letter), Root(nullptr), Left(nullptr), Right(nullptr){
        };


    };

    struct Compare
    {
        bool operator()(const TreeOfLetters& a, const TreeOfLetters& b)
        {
            return a.Value < b.value;
        }
    };

    std::priority_queue<TreeOfLetters, std::vector<TreeOfLetters>, Compare> queue;

public:
    Huffman(std::initializer_list<HType> _Values, std::initializer_list<char> _Chars) : queue(Compare()) {}
    Huffman(const Huffman& orig) = delete;

};
```

or you can implement the comparison as a lambda

```
std::priority_queue<TreeOfLetters, std::vector<TreeOfLetters>, [](const TreeOfLetters& a, const TreeOfLetters& b){return a.Value < b.value;}> queue;
```

You should restrict your HType to basic values using some traits, or else you have to implement the ">" operator for the actual HType you want to use.

See also @Piotr Skotnicki comment above.

Comment: Could you tell me what overloading of operator() do? Is there a way to make it works using lamdas?

Comment: You are overloading the () operator, i.e. you can call an object of the Compare struct as obj(a, b), i.e. as a function. You could probably use a lambda

Comment: Ok I get rid of 2 from 3 of warnings. Now I receive a warning  there  return a.Value < b.Value; unable to resolve identifier. And another  there  std::priority_queue<TreeOfLetters, std::set<TreeOfLetters>, Compare> queue; unable to resolve identifier queue

Comment: You might need to overload the "<"  operator for the actual HType

Comment: What does it stands for Huffman(std::initializer_list<HType> _Values, std::initializer_list<char> _Chars) : queue(Compare()) {} ?

Comment: Just made a empty constructor to have something to compile. If this is unclear I recommend you read up on c++.

Comment: Why not use the lambda? lambdas are just syntactic sugar for functors; [the can definitely be used as the comparator for a `priority_queue`, with slightly less boilerplate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15307604/364696). The functor `struct` works, don't get me wrong, but if the OP wants a lambda, they can use it.