# how to convert java priority queue to c++ priority queue?

Tags: java, c++

I am rewriting Java code as C++ code and am having a problem duplicating Java's priority queue..

The Java priority queue's compare function looks like the following:

```
  public int compareTo(Item that) {
    if (this.dist < that.dist)
      return -1;
    if (this.dist > that.dist)
      return 1;
    return 0;
  }
```

and I made a compare function in C++, however it is not working correctly:

```
struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(Item it1, Item it2)
    {
        if(it1.dist > it2.dist)
            return true;
    }
};
```

it is my c++ code priority queue

I call priority queue like this

```
priority_queue<Item, vector<Item>, cmp> que;
```

but, Java's order and C++'s order is different..

help me please

If this is not enough example code, I can provide my whole code. Java and C++ code

Comment: `bool operator()(Item it1, Item it2)`  In C++, pass by const reference, not by value.  Don't use Java as a model in writing C++ code. `bool operator()(const Item& it1, const Item& it2)`

Comment: C++ version implements [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering), so it basically cannot handle values of equal priority. Java version can handle equal priority, but will return values of equal priority in arbitrary order (not FIFO or LIFO), so it's generally best not to have values of equal priority. If you don't have values of equal priority, then yes, you can convert.

Comment: @Andreas: `std::priority_queue` handles equal values just fine.

Comment: @Andreas: If it needs to, yes. Usually, it doesn't need to, since the relative order of equal elements is unspecified, so it's fine to assume that `a` can be placed after `b` if `!(a < b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your comparison operator as

```
struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(const Item & it1, const Item & it2)    // pass by a const reference
    {
        return it1.dist > it2.dist;
    }
};
```

You can also define it as a free function.

Comment: i fix them but it has infinity loop haha.. it seems not priority problem thank you~~

Comment: @ParkYeoungJun Maybe you can post it as another question.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(Item it1, Item it2)
    {
        if(it1.dist > it2.dist)
            return true;
    }
};
```

The `if` check should ideally be reversed:

```
if ( it1.dist < it2.dist)
```

Since `priority_queue` expects something that is equivalent to `std::less`.

Further, you can simply `return`:

```
bool operator()(Item it1, Item it2)
{
    return  it1.dist < it2.dist;
}
```

Importantly, the `Item` argument must ideally be `const` and by-reference:

```
bool operator()(const Item& it1, const Item& it2)
{
    return  it1.dist < it2.dist;
}
```

If you are using C++11 or higher compiler (which I presume), you can simply use lambdas instead of `struct` having `operator()` defined. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15307604/264325)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't set a condition to 'return false' in C++ cmp

```
struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(Item it1, Item it2)
    {
        if(it1.dist > it2.dist)
            return true;
        else 
            return false
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix your returned value:

```
struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(Item it1, Item it2)
    {
        return (it1.dist > it2.dist)

    }
};
```